# router props and custom props with typescript react router dom for functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

As stated in the title i want to import into my Component react router props and custom props.

My Route looks like this:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/logon/:name"
  render={(p)=>(<Content/>)}>
</Route>
```

Here i get this error:
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'CompProps': name, history, location, match

The error comes from my Component which looks like this:

```
import {RouteComponentProps} from "react-router-dom";

interface CompProps extends RouteComponentProps {
  name: string;
}
export const Content: React.FC<CompProps> = ({
  name,
  match,
}) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <p>test</p>
    </section>
  );
};
```

Im a beginner to TS, but in my opinion the RouteComponentProps should contain (name, history, location) why it TS throws the error on me.
And what is the best practice to pass custom props and Router props to the component?

Here is a screenshot of the error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm it seems like what you are doing is correct, can we get a screenshot of the error?

this is what i usually do.

```
type Props = { id: string };

function Content({ name, match }: RouteComponentProps<Props>) {
  return (
    <section>
      <p>Got match: {match.params.id} on name: {name}</p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Change the spread to

`render={(p)=>(<Content {...p} name="name" />)}>`

does `RouteComponentProps` already expose `name`? so you just want to remove it and do

```
function Content({ name, match }: RouteComponentProps) {
  return (
    <section>
      <p>Got match: {match.params.id} on name: {name}</p>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: i added a screeenshot as requested.

Comment: yea just do 

`render={(p)=>(<Content/>)}>`

Comment: just add a comment, you are declaring `name` as `ContentProps` but never passing it down on `<Content />` <-- here name is missing, so you either remove `name` from `ContentProps` and just do `Content({ name, match }: RouteComponentProps)` or explicity pass `name` like `<Content name="name" {...p} />`

Comment: there are helper functions like useLocation or useHistory , that way i could also get the props. But is this the best practise.

Means then i should import RouteComponentProps only in connection with component={Content} but how i pass then the custom props down to my Content component?

Comment: Thanks man, the name props is not needed cause react router is picking it up in the previous route. I was confused by the RouteComponentProps, however this way i get everything. Router Props and custom props. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since "name" is a path-param it should be only accessible via the match object.

You are extending RouterProps with your name-Property. This seems to be okay. But declaring your Functional Component as

```
export const Content: React.FC<CompProps> = ({
   name,
   match,
}) => {
   ...
}
```

seems to be wrong. I would expect to define the component as

```
export const Content: React.FC<CompProps> = (props: CompProps) => {
   const name = props.match.params.name
   return ...;
};
```

Comment: yes you are right, i removed it. also i marked it as solved.thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Route.render`, you need to spread the props that it provides onto your component, otherwise they won't be present when the `Content` component renders. In your code, change this:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/logon/:name"
  render={(p)=>(<Content/>)}>
</Route>
```

to this

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/logon/:name"
  render={(p)=>(<Content {...p} />)}>
</Route>
```

Comment: But when i spread the props with TS i receive another error on the route =>

Property 'name' is missing in type '{ history: History<unknown>; location: Location<unknown>; match: match<{ name: string; }>; staticContext?: StaticContext | undefined; }' but required in type 'CompProps'.ts(2741)
Content.tsx(5, 3): 'name' is declared here.